# Magento 2 devbox reset scipt command not found m2devbox-reset.[bat|sh]

Tags: magento2, devbox-beta

I am trying to reset Magento devbox after restarting my mac and i keep getting the following error when running the command in the root folder.

> user-iMac:build-7204cee62e1e6ccb35bbdfc977c5e522 user$
>   m2devbox-reset.[bat|sh]
>   -bash: m2devbox-reset.[bat: command not found
>   -bash: sh]: command not found

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was reading the documentation and it said use m2devbox-reset.[bat|sh] What it should have said is use m2devbox-reset.sh on mac and m2devbox-reset.bat on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you've downloaded the **macOS** version (which contains .sh scripts) and not the **Windows Pro** version (which contains .bat files). If you have the correct version, try running this from your build directory

```
./m2devbox-reset.sh
```

Or, to initialize the containers

```
./m2devbox-init.sh
```